# How does execve prevents vulnerabilities compared to system command

Tags: c++, linux, security

I am referring to [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152177) link,
Basically, consider the input `happy'; useradd 'attacker`, the security advice differentiates between a compliant and non-compliant code -

**Non Complaint Code**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
enum { BUFFERSIZE = 512 };
 
void func(const char *input) {
  char cmdbuf[BUFFERSIZE];
  int len_wanted = snprintf(cmdbuf, BUFFERSIZE,
                            "any_cmd '%s'", input);
  if (len_wanted >= BUFFERSIZE) {
    /* Handle error */
  } else if (len_wanted < 0) {
    /* Handle error */
  } else if (system(cmdbuf) == -1) {
    /* Handle error */
  }
}
```

**Compliant Code**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
 
void func(char *input) {
  pid_t pid;
  int status;
  pid_t ret;
  char *const args[3] = {"any_exe", input, NULL};
  char **env;
  extern char **environ;
 
  /* ... Sanitize arguments ... */
 
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == -1) {
    /* Handle error */
  } else if (pid != 0) {
    while ((ret = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) == -1) {
      if (errno != EINTR) {
        /* Handle error */
        break;
      }
    }
    if ((ret != -1) &&
      (!WIFEXITED(status) || !WEXITSTATUS(status)) ) {
      /* Report unexpected child status */
    }
  } else {
    /* ... Initialize env as a sanitized copy of environ ... */
    if (execve("/usr/bin/any_cmd", args, env) == -1) {
      /* Handle error */
      _Exit(127);
    }
  }
}
```

Assume we pass the same input to both the function with equal privilege, i.e run by root etc etc, How does the second solution ensure that command injection attack is repelled?

My only guess is that, `execve` will refresh your binary image with `any_cmd`and use input `happy'; useradd 'attacker` as args to `any_cmd`. So we will be have a return value equivalent to "invalid parameters". Is my understanding right? Or is there something deeper than my understanding which I am missing?

Comment: Which part of the respective manuals of `execve` and `system` did you find unclear?

Comment: I am trying understand how the same input will not cause problem in execve as compared to system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is indeed that with the `system` function you can launch whatever your shell can execute, so you basically can have shell injections with multiple commands. Whereas with `execve` first you specify a specific binary to execute, so you're pretty much sure that there is only one command executed (except if you `execve` a shell..). Also since you give a complete path to `execve` you avoid hacks based on modifying the `HOME` or the current working directory.

So yes, your understanding is rather right